# SQL: Select MAX value from 2 conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 1 table and 4 columns. I would like to get max value from visit and spending with use condition as max visit first and max spending second.

[image]

The result should be shown on the YELLOW highlight on Image above.

For my code below. Please help me in a better way to do this.

```
select tt.*
from #max_location as tt,
     (select member_number, 
             max(max_visit) as maxvisit,
             max(spending) as maxspending
      from #max_location
      group by member_number) as max_visit
where tt.member_number = max_visit.member_number 
  and tt.max_visit = max_visit.maxvisit
  and tt.spending = max_visit.maxspending 
order by tt.member_number desc
```

Comment: Please add your RDBMS tag

Comment: can you rephrase the question plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the ANSI/ISO SQL way of writing the query:

```
select tt.*
from #max_location tt
join (
       select member_number, 
              max(max_visit) as max_visit,
              max(spending)  as max_spending
       from #max_location
       group by member_number
     ) as mv on mv.member_number = tt.member_number
            and mv.max_visit     = tt.max_visit 
            and mv.max_spending  = tt.spending 
order by tt.member_number desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      member_number, 
            MAX(max_visit) AS maxvisit,
            MAX(spending) AS maxspending
FROM        #max_location 
GROUP BY    member_number
```